# sql update для n-количества where

Tags: sql

Есть база с таблицами: `user`, `price`, `price_row`.
Нужно обновить некоторые поля из таблицы `price_rows`, для прайсов из таблицы `price`, которые были загружены определённым `user`.

Все, до чего дошёл, это

```html
   update price_rows set search_result=null, chosen_manually_donor_model_id=null, found_donor_model_id=null where price_id=(select id from prices where user_id=1);
```

Но, это решение не работает, а как сделать или найти ответ увы не нашёл пока...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение, вместо where `=` пишем where `in`

```
update price_rows set search_result=null, chosen_manually_donor_model_id=null, found_donor_model_id=null where price_id IN (select id from prices where user_id=1);
```

Comment: Если БД позволяет и ресурсы критичны, то можно использовать `UPDATE — JOIN`...

Comment: А можете полный пример привести?

Comment: Для мускуля, [первый из гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query/1262848#1262848); для postgres'а будет аналогично... у sqlite'а таких разширений нет. Про остальные БД не скажу...